# cordova-plugin-google-analytics not tracking the analytics data in cordova-ios 6.1

Tags: cordova

I am trying to track analytics in Cordova using cordova-plugin-google-analytics v1.9.0 . But it seems the data is not tracking on google analytics console.

Code:

```
onDeviceReady: function () {
     app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
   
     window.ga.startTrackerWithId('UA-66224400-1', 30)
}

window.ga.trackView('login');
```